# Creating a Selection List (WearableListView)

Tags: wear-os

https://developer.android.com/design/wear/patterns.html#Selection hints the use of  `WearableListView` to create a wearable compatible ListView, but there is no details on how to actually implement it. How can I use it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a sample project in Android SDK folder (`android-sdk\samples\android-20\wearable\Notifications`) that has implemented this

Comment: Anyone seen this but with sub preference list aswell? I.e. clicking one preference open up another list.

Comment: The Timer sample is a less bulky example than Notifications that doesn't have much more than just the WearableListView. You can look at how it is implemented here: http://developer.android.com/samples/Timer/Wearable/src/com.example.android.wearable.timer/SetTimerActivity.html#. (Check out the res/ and src/ folders under Wearable.)

Comment: The [Timer Sample can be found here](https://developer.android.com/samples/Timer/index.html)